# C++ character encoding when converting from string to const char* for Ruby FFI interface

Tags: c++, ruby, encoding, ffi

I am using an external C++ lib that does some HTTPS communication and provides the XML server response. On serverside the response is encoded via `ISO-8859-15` and I get a `std::string` that represents that response out of the API. When I print it out / write it to a file it looks proper.

The `std::string` and an `int` error code have to be passed to my external caller. So I return both values inside a struct:

```
extern "C" {
  struct FoobarResponse {
    const char* responseText;
    int returnCode;
  };
}
```

Unfortunately I have to convert the `std::string` response into a `const char*` C-style string representation with help of `std::c_str()` before. Reason: My caller is a Ruby script making use of Ruby FFI to communicate with my C++ lib, and interlanguage type conversion here is Ruby::string -> C::const char*.

Interesting here: If I `std::cout` the converted string after I put it into the struct, it is still ok.

The problem: When handling the server response on Ruby side, it is broken. Instead of the original answer like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<Foobar xmlns="http://www.foobar.com/2012/XMLSchema">
  ...
</Foobar>
```

I receive a string obviously containing non printable characters which is always broken at the beginning and at the end.

```
?O[
l version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<Foobar xmlns="http://www.foobar.com/2012/XMLSchema">
</Fo??
```

In fact the string contains linebreaks, carriage returns and tabs at least, maybe more.

I tried to `:force_encoding` the string on Ruby side as `ASCII-8BIT`, `ISO-8859-15` and `UTF-8`, no change.
I tried to base64 encode on C++ side before putting the string into the struct and base64 decode on Ruby side using [this code](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/common/base64.html), no change.

I had countless attepts to convert the string using `Iconv` as well, no change.

I also tried to remove non printable characters from the string before putting it into the struct, but I failed on that.

I have no idea what is going on here and running out of options.
Can someone point me into the right direction?

Regards
Felix

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value returned by `c_str()` is destroyed as soon as the `std::string` goes out of scope.
If you intend to pass this value to your script you should allocate memory and copy the string into your newly allocated space. See this example: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

You should also ensure the ruby script will correctly release memory.

I think this is what is explained there: https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Examples.

Example with a struct passed to Ruby from C:
https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Examples#-structs

Comment: I do not pass strings from C to Ruby. I use the struct mentioned above. The struct is created by my C library and the memory used by the struct is also released afterwards. On Ruby side I mirror the struct an can access it. The strings in the struct are accessible. They are only malformed. If the memory was destroyed too early, I would not have access to the string within Ruby, would I?

Comment: But your struct contains a `char*` member. You should allocate the memory for this `char*` and copy the `c_str()` into this newly allocated space. You should also release this memory BEFORE releasing the memory for your struct.

Comment: You would access the memory but it would be full of garbage. This is exactly what you see.

Comment: Feel like the fool I am. I did not allocate memory for the strings inside the struct. Works now. Thx @fjardon, upvoted.